Why are these cracks happening mostly on top of doors?
What in the world (Kansas City) is going on here? I bought this 1986-built house about five years ago, and I noticed the first crack about 8 months ago, but now they are pretty much on top of all the doors. Room doors and some closet doors. What is causing them? Should I be concerned? How to fix them?


This is Kansas City

Are the doors staying even with their frames?  Has the local weather changed, either very wet or very dry compared to other years?

Some doors are fine but other are out of alignment. It has been really rainy this year.

IDK, looks like drywall joints to me, except for that last one, obvs.
